# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am following the [Yii Blog tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/comment.create), and am stuck at this error while doing the comments section.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'post_id' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_comment` (`status`, `content`, `author`, `email`, `url`, `create_time`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5)
```

This same error was on status first, but I set the default value for it in the database. But this time its post_id, I dont know how to work it out. Post ID is the FK from another table. [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.design) is the whole database design.

Thanks!

Comment: You havent set the post_id value in the insert query. You need to set its value as its a foreign key

Comment: Here it is, http://codepad.org/EO50vNeN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your "post_id" attribute, which probably is your primary key, is not set to "auto increment" or is setup with "not null" in your Database. Take a look at the following ORM. Compare it with yours and fix your DB-sided error. And don't forget to upgrade you model via. GII!

[image]

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tbl_comment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_comment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_comment` (
  `post_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `content` TEXT NULL COMMENT ' ',
  `author` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(511) NULL,
  `create_time` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Else, if "post_id" is not your primary key and is not set as "auto increment" you can try  this to fix it:

**Solution 1) Make "post_id" set before save/update in php like:**

```
$model = new Tbl_comment; //hope this is your Yii model name...
$model->post_id = 123

if(!$model->save()) {
   var_dump($model->errors);
}
```

**Solution 2) Add a default value in your database ORM on attribute "post_id". (Cause i dont know your relation and ORM right.)**

[image]

```
-----------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tbl_comment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_comment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tbl_comment` (
  `post_id` INT NULL DEFAULT someDefault,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `content` TEXT NULL COMMENT ' ',
  `author` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(511) NULL,
  `create_time` DATETIME NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Table details:**

[image]

Comment: Here is the ER of my schema, http://i.imgur.com/37H2B1j.png?1 Once I set the default value for post_id, I got the same exception for 'id'. 

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_comment` (`status`, `post_id`, `content`, `author`, `email`, `url`, `create_time`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6)

Comment: Where is the field `id` comes from? You said your error is about `post_id`. If field `id` is also not PK/NOTNULL/NODEFAULT, configure field `id` as PK/NOTNULL/AUTO-INCREMENT?! Its the same you did to `post_id` make `id` as primary key and put "autoincrement" on it (field AI in workbench), ok?

Comment: @user1502, take a look at the last screenshot i added right now. It shows you how to configure it right.

Comment: After doing the AI, I get this, CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`tbl_comment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_comment_post` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_comment` (`status`, `post_id`, `content`, `author`, `email`, `url`, `create_time`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6)

Comment: I am sorry, it says you must have 20 reputation to talk.

Comment: I did rejoin, but it still says you need 20 rep to talk :(

Comment: Okey .... looks like the repu needs some time... Your error is about your ORM definition. Your table "tbl_comment" and its attribute "post_id" is constrained to "tbl_post" and its attribute "id". So if you create a new "tbl_comment" you need to insert a existing KEY from table "tbl_post" in "tbl_comment" attribute "post_id" by using php `$model->post_id = $postModel->id`. Thats why it fails. Read about contraints please.

Comment: $comment->post_id=$this->id; is already there in the addComment() of post model. I tried putting CVarDumper::dump($this->id); Yii::app()->end(); above it, but it doesn't show anything. I figure I messed up writing the code somewhere, will go over the basics again and try copy pasting the code from tutorial. Also I am able to chat now!

Comment: I recreated everything, getting the exception again,

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_comment` (`content`, `author`, `email`, `create_time`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3)